# Searching ID's within a modern SharePoint 2013 list

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, search, query

I have a List with Project Info, it has 500+ items as if for now and it will double over the period of time. I would like an efficient way to search projects with ID (OOB SharePoint column).

When I use the Search box within the list it doesn't resturn accurate results and would like to restrict the search to show me ID's only within that Project List.I have tried using the WebPart's like "Text Filter" under the Filters Webpart but it doesn't work.

Any other suggestions. I have also reIndexed the list from the list setting - advanced settings options.

**For Ex** I tried looking for ID 4935 and I get results for 4324

[image]
[image]

Comment: "Text Filter" under the Filters Web part doesn't work or show inaccurate result?